# Parsing errors when writing to a json file from python

Tags: json, python-3.x, jsonlint

I have seen similar questions yet not sure what do I need to change in my case to make it a valid json.
I have a list of dictionaries like this:

```
dicts = [{'date': '2018-12-11',
  'target_currency': 'DKK',
  'exchange_rate': 7.4641,
  'base_currency': 'EUR'},
 {'date': '2018-12-11',
  'target_currency': 'GBP',
  'exchange_rate': 0.90228,
  'base_currency': 'EUR'},
...]
```

which I have converted to .json like this:

```
        with open('cleaned.json', 'w') as f:
            for d in dict2:
                json.dump(d, f)
                f.write(',')
```

to get this error on https://jsonlint.com/.

```
{
    "date": "2018-12-11",
    "target_currency": "USD",
    "exchange_rate": 1.1379,
    "base_currency": "EUR"
}, {
    "date": "2018-12-11",
    "target_currency": "JPY",
    "exchange_rate": 128.75,
    "base_currency": "EUR"
}, {
    "date": "2018-12-11",
    "target_currency": "BGN",
    "exchange_rate": 1.9558,
    "base_currency": "EUR"



Error: Parse error on line 6:
...e_currency": "EUR"}, {   "date": "2018-1
----------------------^
Expecting 'EOF', got ','
```

When I tried to change comma for a new line separator, f.write('\n'), I got this error:

```
Error: Parse error on line 6:
..._currency": "EUR"} { "date": "2018-12-
----------------------^
Expecting 'EOF', '}', ',', ']', got '{'
```

Apparently I am  writing into a file incorrectly. What am I doing wrong?

I have also tried  writing it into a .jsonl (json lines) format with with open('cleaned.jsonl', 'w') and f.write('\n').
yet I still have

```
JSONDecodeError: Extra data: line 2 column 1 (char 98)
```

when I load it again using json.load().

Comment: No need to loop, just dump `dicts`. That is, if you want regular JSON array of JSON objects. If you want to create `ndjson`/`jsonl` - say it, in this case you don't need the comma.

Comment: it did not work. I tried  with open('cleaned.json', 'w') as f:
            json.dump(dict2, f)
            f.write('\n')

Comment: with your suggestion,  Error: Parse error on line 101:
...ge_rate": 7.8498 },
----------------------^
Expecting 'STRING', 'NUMBER', 'NULL', 'TRUE', 'FALSE', '{', '[', got 'EOF'

Comment: however, with with open('.cleaned.jsonl', 'r') as f:
 json.dump(dict2, f)
            f.write('\n')  it worked.  so your solution only works for 'jsonl' .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
import json

data = [{'date': '2018-12-11',
  'target_currency': 'DKK',
  'exchange_rate': 7.4641,
  'base_currency': 'EUR'},
 {'date': '2018-12-11',
  'target_currency': 'GBP',
  'exchange_rate': 0.90228,
  'base_currency': 'EUR'}]

with open('data.json', 'w') as f:
    json.dump(data, f, indent=4)


with open('data.jsonl', 'w') as f:
    for item in data:
        f.write(json.dumps(item) + '\n')
```

output `data.json`:

```
[
    {
        "date": "2018-12-11",
        "target_currency": "DKK",
        "exchange_rate": 7.4641,
        "base_currency": "EUR"
    },
    {
        "date": "2018-12-11",
        "target_currency": "GBP",
        "exchange_rate": 0.90228,
        "base_currency": "EUR"
    }
]
```

This you can read as a whole with `json.load()`.

output `data.jsonl`:

```
{"date": "2018-12-11", "target_currency": "DKK", "exchange_rate": 7.4641, "base_currency": "EUR"}
{"date": "2018-12-11", "target_currency": "GBP", "exchange_rate": 0.90228, "base_currency": "EUR"}
```

Note that ndjson/jsonl you cannot read with `json` module as one file, you need to read/parse line by line. There are third party libraries to handle ndjson/jsonl conveniently.
Also, you cannot validate ndjson/jsonl on https://jsonlint.com

Comment: yes, thats fine. I can open either with json.load() or .read().splitlines(). thank you v much.

Comment: In case of jsonl - no need to read the whole content, just iterate over file handler.